# Django: what's the simplest way to test if object is in set

Tags: django

Just a non-critical question that has bothered me after trying to find answers in the doc to no avail.

```
class Book(models.Model)
    authors = ManyToManyField(Author)

homer = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
iliad = Book.objects.get(pk=2)

iliad.authors.filter(pk=homer.pk).exists()
Book.objects.filter(name='Iliad', authors__in=homer).exists()
```

I believe the last two asserts will test if Homer is the author of Iliad. But I kind of dislike the (pk=homer.pk) portion and am wondering if there's any construct that will allow me to test if an object (assuming we already have it from a "get") exists in a queryset?

```
(homer in iliad.authors)
```

While the above expression may also work, and is arguably more pythonic, it may retrieve unnecessarily too many authors back from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case `homer in iliad.authors` would be only slightly slower than `exists` version. Most of the books have one or two authors so getting all from DB should not be a problem.

I think there is no way to do this in Django faster without using filter in way you used, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think there's any other obvious way either after some more research.

Answer (score 0):

[Django's queryset code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L138) implements some optimization when using the `in` operator.

To get better insight, I'd try timing the use of `in` on the queryset vs. your other examples, for big and small datasets.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, looking at the django source, assuming nothing is cached so far, in would result in (a whole prefetch or iterating results one by one). In both cases, it won't be faster than a quick exists check. so I'm unsure of using in universally.